# How do I multiply the contents of an array with a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, list

I need to multiply the contents of an array in Python with a For Loop, and its not working.
Basically this is the code I need:

```
g = [["flat"] in range(200)]
```

I basically need 200 "flat"s stored in an array called g.
Can anyone help?

I expected it to store 200 'flat's in the array g, but instead, when I tried to print the contents of the array, it just printed `["False"]`

Comment: @tripleee I fixed the duplicate link. You may want to keep this one on your short list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g = ['flat'] * 200
```

Output:

```
['flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat', 'flat']
```

Comment: Of course, you don't need the loop at all. `g = ['flat'] * 200`

Comment: Note that this only works as expected if the items are value types rather than reference types.

Comment: @Ouroborus What are "value types" and "reference types"?

Comment: @KellyBundy Good question, because something like that doesn't exist. The correct description would have been "mutable values" and "immutable values".

Comment: @KellyBundy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type_and_reference_type

Comment: @Ouroborus Now look on that page in the "Classification per language" table for Python and you'll see no value types whatsoever.

Comment: @KellyBundy Is there some distinction that is generally important in practice?

Comment: @Ouroborus As Matthias said, you probably meant the issue of mutable vs immutable. Immutables like strings are safe to repeat this way, while repeating mutables like lists often causes problems (almost every day there's a new duplicate question about that on SO).

Comment: Yes, you could  do string * n, but its less messy this way. At least, for me

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The other post was trying to get the opposite answer of the one i was trying to get